# how to call back unique together constraints as a field django

Tags: django, unique-constraint

i'm trying to call back unique constraints field , in my project i have to count number of M2M selected

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    room_no = models.ForeignKey(Room,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,related_name='rooms')
    takes_by = models.ManyToManyField(Vistor)

    @property
    def no_persons(self):
        qnt =  Booking.objects.filter(takes_by__full_information=self).count()#but this doesnt  work
        return qnt
```

> Cannot query "some room information": Must be "Vistor" instance.

```
class Vistor(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=14)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['full_name','dob','city'],name='full_information')
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.full_name} - {self.city} - {self.dob}'
```

it it possible to access `full_information` through `Booking` model ? thank you ..

Comment: It is unclear to me *what* you exactly want to achieve. Can you share some sample data with the expected result and explain *what* that result represents?

Comment: for example i've selected 4 people in `Booing` im trying to count that 4 person i want to display number of persons per booking

Comment: So you simply want to count the number of related visitors? Then it looks like `self.taken_by.count()` is sufficient

Comment: but it always returns 0 because i returned  `    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.full_name} - {self.city} - {self.dob}'` it expects this data `{self.full_name} - {self.city} - {self.dob}`

Comment: no, the database does not know anything about the `__str__`, that is a method used by Django to render it for the template, etc. If it returns `0`, then it means you did not add any `Visitor`s to you `Book`ing (yet). You can add a visitor `v` to a `Booking` named `b` with `b.take_by.add(v)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of `Visitor`s related to that booking, you can count these with:

```
@property
def no_persons(self):
    self.taken_by.count()
```

This will make an extra query to the database, therefore it is often better to let the database count these in the query. You can thus remove the property, and query with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Booking.objects.annotate(
    no_persons=Count('takes_by')
)
```

The `Booking`s that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `no_persons` with the number of related `Visitor`s.

Comment: how to use annotate() with `Booking.objects.get(id=id)`or `get_object_or_404(Booking,id=id)` ?

Comment: You can pass a `QuerySet` to `get_object_or_404`, so `get_object_or_404(Booking.objects.annotate(...), id=id)`, or you can work with `Booking.objects.annotate(...).get(id=id)`.